# Adding the row to another table after clicking "Add New Row" button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

I'm an apprentice in Django, javascript, and HTML. I am developing a website that actually helps in filling shift handover(If a company works in shifts, then the associates in the current shift should handover the shift to next person by explaining pending tasks to be completed, scheduled tasks/activities in his/her shift.. etc). During this, I have encountered a problem.

I had written 6 HTML files for 6 tables separately. And I had written Add new row, edit, save, and delete functionalities for 6 tables using one jquery script. Now I need to include all 6 tables in one HTML file and should link that one jquery script such that all functionalities(add, delete, edit and save) should work individually for 6 tables.

But here if I click on add new row button on one table, the row is getting added on another table. Kindly help on this.

HTML Code for two tables(table1 id is DynamicTable5, table2 id is DynamicTable6)

```js
"use strict";
function IterarCamposEdit(t, n) {
  function i(t) {
    if (null == colsEdi) return !0;
    for (var n = 0; n < colsEdi.length; n++) if (t == colsEdi[n]) return !0;
    return !1;
  }
  var o = 0;
  t.each(function () {
    o++, "buttons" != $(this).attr("name") && i(o - 1) && n($(this));
  });
}
function FijModoNormal(t) {
  $(t).parent().find("#bAcep").hide(),
    $(t).parent().find("#bCanc").hide(),
    $(t).parent().find("#bEdit").show(),
    $(t).parent().find("#bElim").show(),
    $(t).parents("tr").attr("id", "");
}
function FijModoEdit(t) {
  $(t).parent().find("#bAcep").show(),
    $(t).parent().find("#bCanc").show(),
    $(t).parent().find("#bEdit").hide(),
    $(t).parent().find("#bElim").hide(),
    $(t).parents("tr").attr("id", "editing");
}
function ModoEdicion(t) {
  return "editing" == t.attr("id");
}
function rowAcep(t) {
  var n = $(t).parents("tr"),
    i = n.find("td");
  ModoEdicion(n) &&
    (IterarCamposEdit(i, function (t) {
      var n = t.find("input").val();
      t.html(n);
    }),
    FijModoNormal(t),
    params.onEdit(n));
}
function rowCancel(t) {
  var n = $(t).parents("tr"),
    i = n.find("td");
  ModoEdicion(n) &&
    (IterarCamposEdit(i, function (t) {
      var n = t.find("div").html();
      t.html(n);
    }),
    FijModoNormal(t));
}
function rowEdit(t) {
  var n = $(t).parents("tr"),
    i = n.find("td");
  ModoEdicion(n) ||
    (IterarCamposEdit(i, function (t) {
      var n = t.html(),
        i = '<div style="display: none;">' + n + "</div>",
        o = '<input class="form-control input-sm"  value="' + n + '">';
      t.html(i + o);
    }),
    FijModoEdit(t));
}
function rowElim(t) {
  $(t).parents("tr").remove(), params.onDelete();
}
function rowAgreg() {
  if (0 == $tab_en_edic.find("tbody tr").length) {
    var t = "";
    (i = $tab_en_edic.find("thead tr").find("th")).each(function () {
      "buttons" == $(this).attr("name")
        ? (t += colEdicHtml)
        : (t += "<td></td>");
    }),
      $tab_en_edic.find("tbody").append("<tr>" + t + "</tr>");
  } else {
    var n = $tab_en_edic.find("tr:last");
    n.clone().appendTo(n.parent());
    var i = (n = $tab_en_edic.find("tr:last")).find("td");
    i.each(function () {
      "buttons" == $(this).attr("name") || $(this).html("");
    });
  }
}
function TableToCSV(t) {
  var n = "",
    i = "";
  return (
    $tab_en_edic.find("tbody tr").each(function () {
      ModoEdicion($(this)) && $(this).find("#bAcep").click();
      var o = $(this).find("td");
      (n = ""),
        o.each(function () {
          "buttons" == $(this).attr("name") || (n = n + $(this).html() + t);
        }),
        "" != n && (n = n.substr(0, n.length - t.length)),
        (i = i + n + "\n");
    }),
    i
  );
}
var $tab_en_edic = null,
  params = null,
  colsEdi = null,
  newColHtml =
    '<div class="btn-group pull-right"><button id="bEdit" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" onclick="rowEdit(this);"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" > </span></button><button id="bElim" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" onclick="rowElim(this);"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" > </span></button><button id="bAcep" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" style="display:none;" onclick="rowAcep(this);"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" > </span></button><button id="bCanc" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" style="display:none;" onclick="rowCancel(this);"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" > </span></button></div>',
  colEdicHtml = '<td name="buttons">' + newColHtml + "</td>";
$.fn.SetEditable = function (t) {
  var n = {
    columnsEd: null,
    $addButton: null,
    onEdit: function () {},
    onDelete: function () {},
    onAdd: function () {},
  };
  (params = $.extend(n, t)),
    this.find("thead tr").append('<th name="buttons"></th>'),
    this.find("tbody tr").append(colEdicHtml),
    ($tab_en_edic = this),
    null != params.$addButton &&
      params.$addButton.click(function () {
        rowAgreg();
      }),
    null != params.columnsEd && (colsEdi = params.columnsEd.split(","));
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>
      Dynamic Editable HTML Table using Javascript, Jquery and Bootstrap with
      add, edit, and Delete Options
    </title>
    <!-- CSS files-->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- page content -->
    <br />
    <h1 class="col-md-12 text-center" style="color: black;">Current Shift</h1>

    <br />
    <div class="table-responsive col-md-10">
      <table
        class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed text-center"
        id="DyanmicTable5"
      >
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-center">
              Current shift
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
              Shift handedover to
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
              Associates names in current shift
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
              Associate names in Next Shift
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
              Shift Handover time
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
              <button id="addNewRow" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                Add New Row
              </button>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              First
            </td>
            <td>
              Second
            </td>
            <td>
              Sushma, &nbsp;Saikiran
            </td>
            <td>
              Venkat
            </td>
            <td>
              15:30
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <br /><br /><br />
    <div class="table-responsive col-md-10">
      <table
        class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed text-center"
        id="DyanmicTable6"
      >
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-center">
              S.No
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
              Tasks List
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
              Monitored in First Shift
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
              Monitored in Second shift
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
              Monitored in Third SHift
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
              <button id="addNewRow2" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                Add New Row
              </button>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              1
            </td>
            <td>
              Monitored Netcool, InfoVista, Cramer, IT IS, DBA, RTMT
              applications
            </td>
            <td>
              Yes
            </td>
            <td>
              Yes
            </td>
            <td>
              Yes
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              2
            </td>
            <td>
              Sending Health Checklists and Reports
            </td>
            <td>
              Yes
            </td>
            <td>
              Yes
            </td>
            <td>
              Yes
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              3
            </td>
            <td>
              Upload Health Checklists in sharepoint
            </td>
            <td>
              Yes
            </td>
            <td>
              Yes
            </td>
            <td>
              Yes
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              4
            </td>
            <td>
              Monitoring Remedy and Updating AMS tracker
            </td>
            <td>
              Yes
            </td>
            <td>
              Yes
            </td>
            <td>
              Yes
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              5
            </td>
            <td>
              GNO TF AMS Master tickets tracker Conciliation aganist remedy
            </td>
            <td>
              Yes
            </td>
            <td>
              Yes
            </td>
            <td>
              Yes
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              6
            </td>
            <td>
              Creating Incidents and SRs on behalf of customers when you got
              mail
            </td>
            <td>
              Yes
            </td>
            <td>
              Yes
            </td>
            <td>
              Yes
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              7
            </td>
            <td>
              Creating P3 incidents for disk usage exceeds 95%
            </td>
            <td>
              Yes
            </td>
            <td>
              Yes
            </td>
            <td>
              Yes
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              8
            </td>
            <td>
              Creating related requests for user created requests
            </td>
            <td>
              Yes
            </td>
            <td>
              Yes
            </td>
            <td>
              Yes
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              9
            </td>
            <td>
              Number of critical alerts noticed
            </td>
            <td>
              7
            </td>
            <td>
              Yes
            </td>
            <td>
              Yes
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              10
            </td>
            <td>
              Number of major alerts noticed
            </td>
            <td>
              4
            </td>
            <td>
              Yes
            </td>
            <td>
              Yes
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              11
            </td>
            <td>
              Number of tickets created for critical alerts
            </td>
            <td>
              1
            </td>
            <td>
              Yes
            </td>
            <td>
              Yes
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              12
            </td>
            <td>
              DC Sharepoint
            </td>
            <td>
              Yes
            </td>
            <td>
              Yes
            </td>
            <td>
              Yes
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              13
            </td>
            <td>
              Continous frequency
            </td>
            <td>
              Yes
            </td>
            <td>
              Yes
            </td>
            <td>
              Yes
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    <!--JS Files-->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="bootstable.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      $("#DyanmicTable5").SetEditable({ $addButton: $("#addNewRow") });
    </script>

    <script>
      $("#DyanmicTable6").SetEditable({ $addButton: $("#addNewRow2") });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please include your HTML and JavaScript code to let everyone understand what you've done so far.

Comment: @Shnmuk Eswar Welcome to StackOverflow! It's easier to help you if you include your code snippet

Comment: @sonali, I have edited my post with code snippets. Please assist